# Google Cloud Storage paginate objects in a bucket (PHP)

Tags: php, pagination, google-cloud-storage

I want to iterate over the objects in a bucket. I REALLY need to paginate this - we have 100's of thousands of objects in the bucket. Our bucket looks like:

```
 bucket/MLS ID/file 1
 bucket/MLS ID/file 2
 bucket/MLS ID/file 3
 ... etc
```

Simplest version of my code follows. I know the value I'm setting into $params['nextToken'] is wrong, I can't figure out how or where to get the right one. $file_objects is a 'Google\Cloud\Storage\ObjectIterator', right?

```
// temp: pages of 10, out of a total of 100. I really want pages of 100
// out of all (in my test bucket, I have about 700 objects)
$params = [
    'prefix'      => $mls_id,
    'maxResults'  => 10,
    'resultLimit' => 100,
    'fields'      => 'items/id,items/name,items/updated,nextPageToken',
    'pageToken'   => NULL
];

while ( $file_objects = $bucket->objects($params) )
{
    foreach ( $file_objects as $object )
    {
        print "NAME: {$object->name()}\n";
    }

    // I think that this might need to be encoded somehow?
    // or how do I get the requested nextPageToken???
    $params['pageToken'] = $file_objects->nextResultToken(); 

}
```

So - I don't understand maxResults vs resultLimit. It would seem that resultLimit would be the total that I want to see from my bucket, and maxResults the size of my page. But maxResults doesn't seem to affect anything, while resultLimit does.

```
maxResults = 100
resultLimit = 10
```

produces 10 objects.

```
maxResults = 10
resultLimit = 100
```

spits out 100 objects.

```
maxResults = 10
resultLimit = 0
```

dumps out all 702 in the bucket, with maxResults having no effect at all. And at no point does "$file_objects->nextResultToken();" give me anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The [`objects`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/bucket?method=objects) method automatically handles pagination for you. It returns an [`ObjectIterator`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/objectiterator) object.

The `resultLimit` parameter limits the total number of objects to return across all pages. The `maxResults` parameter sets the maximum number to return per page.

If you use a `foreach` over the `ObjectIterator` object, it'll iterate through all objects, but note that there are also other methods in `ObjectIterator`, like [`iterateByPage`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.122.0/storage/objectiterator?method=iterateByPage).

Comment: Thanks, jterrace, I got a little further. The "objects" documentation implies (very strongly) that I use it to paginate expressly (pageToken argument). The documentation is very weak, I've been beating my head on this wall for 2 days. More questions, I'm going to try to update my initial question with what I have figured out so far.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it. I found the documentation far too sparse and misleading. The code I came up with:

```
$params = [
    'prefix' => <my prefix here>,
    'maxResults' => 100,
    //'resultLimit' => 0,
    'fields' => 'items/id,items/name,items/updated,nextPageToken',
    'pageToken' => NULL
];
// Note: setting 'resultLimit' to 0 does not work, I found the
//   docs misleading. If you want all results, don't set it at all

// Get the first set of objects per those parameters
$object_iterator = $bucket->objects($params);

// in order to get the next_result_token, I had to get the current 
//   object first. If you don't, nextResultToken() always returns 
//   NULL
$current = $object_iterator->current();
$next_result_token = $object_iterator->nextResultToken();

while ($next_result_token)
{
    $object_page_iterator = $object_iterator->iterateByPage();
    foreach ($object_page_iterator->current() as $file_object )
    {
        print " -- {$file_object->name()}\n";
    }

    // here is where you use the page token retrieved earlier - get
    //   a new set of objects
    $params['pageToken'] = $next_result_token;
    $object_iterator = $bucket->objects($params);

    // Once again, get the current object before trying to get the
    // next result token
    $current = $object_iterator->current();
    $next_result_token = $object_iterator->nextResultToken();
    print "NEXT RESULT TOKEN: {$next_result_token}\n";
}
```

This seems to work for me, so now I can get to the actual problem. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Because I could not parse that solution out of the documentation. If you have a pointer, I would greatly appreciate one.